# How to write the equation of a graph which has two or more different functions togather in that graph?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Like in the graph below the velocity is linear for some time and then becomes exponential.

We know that the equation of the straight line is 
V(t) = m (t-h)+c 
and the equation of the exponential curve is

V(t) = ab^t+c

So what will be the equation of this graph as a whole ? Can we write "V(t) = m (t-h)+ab^t+C" ? Or anything else ? I am confused. Please help me regarding this.[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is piecewise defined. So
$$
v(t)=\begin{cases} m(t-h)+c & \text{if $0\leq t\leq 3$} \\ ab^t+c & \text{if $t\geq 3$}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: what type of graph will have its equation as the sum of different functions ? can you tell please ? e.g what type of the graph is this which has the equation i(t)=Ae^Mt +Be^Nt 
​​

Comment: @bilalkhan It would just be the graph that is the sum of those two functions at each point.  For example, if $f(t)=t+1$ and $g(t)=t^2$, then the function $h(t)=t^2+t+1$ would be the corresponding parabola.  The graph wouldn't split into two pieces.  It would just be the sum of the parts at each point in the domain.